# Anomaly detector with C#

Tags: c#, azure-cognitive-services

I'm using the anomaly detector with .NET 5 and the code [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/anomaly-detector/quickstarts/client-libraries-multivariate?pivots=programming-language-csharp)

What should be the signature of the Main Method?  At the moment it's

```
public  async Task Main(string[] args)
```

I'm getting these error message:

> can't convert type void to system.guid

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
> Error   CS1997  Since 'Program.trainAsync(AnomalyDetectorClient, string, DateTimeOffset, DateTimeOffset, int)' is an async method that returns 'Task', a return keyword must not be followed by an object expression. Did you intend to return 'Task'?   anomaly-detector-quickstart-multivariate    C:\CognitiveSvs\Anomalies\anomaly-detector-quickstart-multivariate\Program.cs   116 Active

Also, there is a statement using Azure.Core.TestFramework; which doesn't seem to exist.  What should I use in its place?

Is there any sample data I can use for univariate and multivariate analysis?

Comment: Is the error fixed if the signature changes to return either `System.Guid` or `Task<System.Guid>` ?

Comment: In line 116 you return a Guid where you shouldn't return anything

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the [example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/anomaly-detector/quickstarts/client-libraries-multivariate?pivots=programming-language-csharp) code is not correct (or not correctly displayed).

The error is not about the `Main` method but, about the `trainAsync` method.

> CS1997 Since 'Program.**trainAsync**(AnomalyDetectorClient, string,
> DateTimeOffset, DateTimeOffset, int)' is an async method that returns
> 'Task', a return keyword must not be followed by an object expression.
> Did you intend to return 'Task'?
> anomaly-detector-quickstart-multivariate
> C:\CognitiveSvs\Anomalies\anomaly-detector-quickstart-multivariate\Program.cs
> 116

Which is described as follows in your link:

```
private async Task trainAsync(AnomalyDetectorClient client, string datasource, DateTimeOffset start_time, DateTimeOffset end_time, int max_tryout = 500)
{
...
```

According the error message you receive, and the [source](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net/blob/main/sdk/anomalydetector/Azure.AI.AnomalyDetector/samples/Sample4_MultivariateDetect.md) for the documentation and the actual code of the method (which returns a `Guid`), this is the correct signature for the `trainAsync` method:

```
private async Task<Guid?> trainAsync(AnomalyDetectorClient client, string datasource, DateTimeOffset start_time, DateTimeOffset end_time, int max_tryout = 500)
{
...
```

Comment: Now I get a message Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State
Error CS5001 Program does not contain a static 'Main' method suitable for an entry point anomaly-detector-quickstart-multivariate C:\CognitiveSvs\Anomalies\anomaly-detector-quickstart-multivariate\CSC 1 Active

Comment: I made the other methods static.  Seems to have fixed the problem.